# Query search, how to pass params from check_box form as a row sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Hi I have a controller function, based on a check_box_form ( so there can by one or more value passed), like this:

```
def show_spells
    #there are 3 params 'elemensts', 'levels', and 'tags'
    if params[:tags].blank?
      @chosen_spells = Spell.where(element: params[:elements], level: params[:levels] ).to_a
    else      
      @chosen_spells = Spell.where( "element = ? and level = ? and tags = ARRAY[?]", params[:elements], params[:levels], params[:tags]).to_a
    end 
  end
```

And it references to a object table:

```
class CreateSpells < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :spells do |t|
      t.string :element
      t.string :level
      t.string :desc
      t.text :tags, array: true, default: []

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The firs query works perfect, but the second one is making a problem, when I pass just one value to elements and levels it doesn't show any resoults, and when I pass more then one walue to elements or levels it show me an error: `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean`

I`m new to SQL query searches, but from what I understand, from [Active Record Query Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches) :

`Object.where(attr: params[:foo])` should be equal to `Object.where("attr = ?", params[:foo])`. And it seems like it isn`t. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different issues here that you're running into. However, I believe all of them are related to bad query syntax. ActiveRecord's query interface is very powerful, but without proper usage, it can throw crazy errors that are hard to debug. A good understanding of SQL will help you navigate it better.

**First**, regarding "pass[ing] more then one value to elements or levels": the `=` operator in Postgres can only compare against a single value, and Rails' parameter binding is very simplistic. When you run this code:

```
Object.where("attr = ?", [1, 2, 3])
```

Rails is going to run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE attr = 1, 2, 3;
```

Which is invalid SQL -- but Rails doesn't know that, so you get a PGError. The proper SQL syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE attr IN (1, 2, 3);
```

And to get that, the best way is to use `where`'s hash syntax:

```
Object.where(attr: [1, 2, 3])
```

**Second**, for an array type, the operation you're looking for to test inclusion, but Rails only knows to test for equality. You have no choice but to just use interpolated params for this, like you're doing, but your syntax is off. The SQL needs to be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM objects WHERE some_array_field @> ARRAY['foo', 'bar'];
```

To get that, `.where("some_array_field @> ARRAY[?]", things)` is your best bet.

**In conclusion**, your code could be written like this:

```
@chosen_spells = Spell.where(element: params[:elements],
                             level:   params[:levels])
                      .where('tags @> ARRAY[?]', params[:tags])
```

And it should work as desired.

Comment: Great answer, can you recomend any free SQL tutorial ?

Comment: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/ is a decent guide. My best suggestion is to figure out how to open the psql prompt for your database (`rails dbconsole` should do it) and then just play around. Try to answer questions about your data, like, how many spells are in your database of a given level? What's the most common element? Which tags are most popular?